# Header files and include for sourcing functions

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I am quite new to C++, coming from an interpreted language I am having a bit of difficulty with understanding how header files relate to libraries and dependencies.

For example, suppose I have the main body of my project:

```
#include <vector>

//----------------------------define some auxiliary function which deals with vectors
void A(std::vector<int> &vect)
{ 
    vect.clear();
}

//----------------------------main body
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vect = {1,2,3}
    A(vect);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Now suppose I want to define the auxiliary function `A()` in a separate `.cpp` file, and still be able to call it from my main `.cpp` file. My question is- for this project, do I have to `#include <vector>` in all `.cpp` files  which use something from that library? If so, do I still need to `#include <vector>` in my `main` file?

I think I understand how header files work, but it is still unclear what happens if I have several files using elements from the same library.

Comment: Just the file that uses the vector needs to include it.

Comment: @MathewHD yes, but do all files which use it have to include it separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just the file that uses the Vector Component needs to include it. You can also include a component when you include another file.

**For Example:**

1. Example.h

```
#include <vector>

//----------------------------define some auxiliary function which deals with vectors
void A(std::vector<int> &vect) { 
    vect.clear();
}
```

2. Example.cp

```
include "Example.h"

//----------------------------main body
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vect = {1,2,3};
    A(vect);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Comment from @Vivick**

You would normally also `#include <vector>` in the main to avoid needing to look up which header file includes which library.

Comment: Though it is good practice to also include `vector` in main to avoid looking up which header includes what

Comment: in your example `main` is using a vector, but does not include the header. If I keep the first line in `main` but replace `Example.h` by something else then `main` is broken. You should include what you use, not rely on includes by other includes

Comment: @Vivick It's not like OP can't do that. I just wanted to show that you don't have to include <vector> in every script but could use a include on the header file instead.

Comment: what can be done and what should be done are two different things. You should at least mention it

Comment: It has already been added as a comment, I can include the comment into the answer if wanted tough.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to include  in all .cpp files. If you #include  in your Example.h or Example.cpp and if you just include one of them in your main file like #include "Example.h" or "Example.cpp", you can use vectors in your main too.

Answer (score 2):

Includes are transitive. `#include foo.h` simply puts the contents of `foo.h` in place of the include-directive.

This is correct, but bad:

```
// foo.h
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> v;

// bar.h 
#include "foo.h"

// main.cpp
#include "bar.h"   
std::vector<int> x;
int main() {}
```

This will compile, but it is very bad style. You should include what you use. If someone looks at `foo.h` only, suppose they realize that `v` is not needed anymore, they will see that no `vector` is used, remove `#include <vector>` and by this break `main.cpp`. You cannot look into all files that include `foo.h` to decide whether the include is needed or not.

This is correct and better:

```
// foo.h
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> v;

// bar.h 
#include "foo.h"

// main.cpp
#include "bar.h"   
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> x;
int main() {}
```

Some recommend to include standard library headers last. In this way you will get an error in case eg `foo.h` forgot to include `<vector>`. Sometimes headers need not the full definition of a type, but only a declaration. In such cases a forward declaration can be used to reduce compile times. The definition is then only supplied in the source by including the header. Example:

```
// foo.h
struct bar;   // forward declaration 
struct foo {
    bar* p;   // pointer, need only declaration, no definition!
    void do_something();
}

// foo.cpp
#include "bar.h"
void foo::do_something() {
    bar b;      // create instance, needs definition
    // ...
}
```

PS: You do not have to worry about including a header too often. Headers are guarded against multiple includes via so called include guards:

```
// moo.h
#ifndef MOO_HEADER_INCLUDE_GUARD
#define MOO_HEADER_INCLUDE_GUARD

// the actual contents

#endif
```

If in one translation unit the same header is included twice, the preprocessor (includes are handled by the preprocessor) will see that the symbol `MOO_HEADER_INCLUDE_GUARD` is already defined and skip the contents of the header.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you create a.h and a.cpp
a.h

```
#pragma once //ensure a.h will only be included once in case multiple c++ include it
#include <vector>
void A(std::vector<int> &vect)
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h" // include your own declarations
void A(std::vector<int> &vect)
{
...
}
```

Whoever includes `a.h` will by a side effect also include `<vector>` but each module (.h) still needs to include all its own dependencies (ie if you need `std::vector` somewhere, you have to include it, otherwise your code might not compile any more if used in another context.